# How do I have an input button and <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```
<a>
Stuff stuff stuff
<input type="Submit" onclick="....">
</a>
```

The problem is...when I click the submit button, it goes to the  instead of onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="Button" onclick="....">
```

Use `Button` type instead of `Submit` :)

If you still want to use `Submit`, just place `return false` after your code eg:

```
<input type="Submit" onclick="doStuff(); return false;">
```

Comment: Yes. The `<a>` (without href=) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Returning false from you on click handler should prevent the default behaviour, e.g.:

```
<a href="index.html">
  Stuff stuff stuff
  <input type="Submit" onclick="alert('test'); return false;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also make an `<a>` look like a button using CSS `display: block` or `display: inline-block`